# Find the nearest Labeled Map Landmark/Place given a Latitude and Longitude

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, maps

Am working on a Google Maps app targeting users that might need directions about certain locations only known by their Latitude and Longitude in the app.

The problem is that the directions need to be resolved to Human-readable names, and best if any location can be stated relative to another near-by location, something like:

`Harambe Coffe Shop *near* Marvin Bank`

as this would help users getting this info on phone devices that cant display maps and those in remote areas where exact location names aren’t available.

So, given a Latitude and Longitude, how can I find the nearest landmarks or features so that I generate a name relative to these?

Algorithms for a brute-force attack on this are also welcome :-)

Thanks in advance to all contributors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to search for objects near a point in some rectilinear co-ordinates, use [k-dimensional trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).